# How to return a pandas series from a for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series which looks like this:

```
dish_name
Chiken Biryani    3
Mutton Biryani    1
Paneer Biryani    4
Paneer Pulav      2
sandwitch         2
```

I am calculating (3/(3+1+4+2+2) then second element (1/(3+1+4+2+2) and so on till the end of series.. Which I am doing it with following code in python:

```
def dish_push(dish_data):
    dish_number = len(dish_data)
    for i in range(dish_number):
        dish = ((dish_data[i])/(dish_data[0:dish_number].sum()))*100
    return dish
```

But when I pass a series to this function it outputs only the last value.

```
dish_push(dish_quantity_sold)
Out[291]: 16.666666666666664
```

Where as I am expecting like this..

```
25.0
8.33333333333
33.3333333333
16.6666666667
16.6666666667
```

Am I doing some mistake in return statement? Why is it printing the last value? please help.

Comment: Well you overwrite `dish` on each iteration you should append to a list or similar container and return this, also this is very similar to your previous question, what's wrong with `(s/s.sum()) * 100`?

Comment: If you already have a pandas series why not doing something like `100*df.x/df.x.sum()`

Comment: Also your indentation looks incorrect, can you fix this as indentation matters in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `dish` is your series with the values `[3, 1, 4, 2, 2]`, you can get the result you're looking for without iteration by doing the following:

```
result = dish / dish.sum() * 100
```

Comment: The OP want's percentages so you need to multiply by 100

Comment: @jonchar  Ya that's what I am looking for.. But, if i want to return a series in my above loop how to do it?

Comment: Use the loop to generate a list of the values you want to return - start with an empty list and append each new value. Then create a series using the list.

Answer (score 3):

jonchar already showed the best way to do your specific task, but regarding your question, the problem is that each time through the loop, you are overwriting the `dish` variable with the series from that iteration.  At the end, you return the last `dish` value from the loop.

What you would need to do is something like this:

```
def dish_push(dish_data):
    dish_number = len(dish_data)
    new_data = np.zeros_like(dish_data)
    for i in range(dish_number):
        new_data[i] = ((dish_data[i])/(dish_data.sum()))*100
    return new_data
```

This would create an array of zeros, put each value in that array, and return the new array after the values have been added.

However, it can be simplified further by using `enumerate` and looping over the data directly.  In each cycle of the loop, this will give you each data point and the index of that data point.  Also, you can compute the sum once rather than every time.  This also allows you to change the original data in-place, since the sum is already calculated and thus won't change when you change a value.  And since the values are changed in-place, you don't have to return anything, since you can just use the array you passed to `dish_push` (although I will leave the return in just in case):

```
def dish_push(dish_data):
    dish_sum = dish_data.sum()/100
    for i, idata in enumerate(dish_data):
        dish_data[i] = idata /dish_sum
    return dish_data
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is a rather ugly solution but what you expect it to do is the following:

```
def dish_push(dish_data):
    dish_number = len(dish_data)
    dish = []
    for i in range(dish_number):
        dish.append(((dish_data[i])/(dish_data[0:dish_number].sum()))*100)
    return dish
```

That is, you don't overwrite the result in every iteration but append it to the list.